# how can I add a zero only to a specific value without affecting the other values?

Tags: r

how can I add a zero only to a specific value without affecting the other values, this if it fulfills the condition that my value has 12 digits and I need it to have 13 digits and the others 10 digits?

```
x=c(102030301,223456783,5234567123,916784443214)

if_else(x>=12, false = paste0("0",x),true = stringr::str_pad(x, 10, side = "left", pad = 0))
```

I tried this code but it did not give me the expected result.

I would like to obtain the following result this is to apply it to a database with an id of more than 1000 records

```
"0102030301"   "0223456783"   "5234567123"   "0916784443214"
```

Comment: Thank you Gregor Thomas and SteveM for the answers, I was able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems.

1. `x` is numeric so when you test `x >= 12` its value, not the number of characters. Use `nchar(x)` to get the number of characters.
2. Your conditions are reversed - `if_else(x>=12, ..., true = stringr::str_pad(x, 10, side = "left", pad = 0))` only padding 12-length numbers up to 10-length... not doing anything.
3. I don't know what you want to happen if the input has 11 characters... with this code (modeled after yours) it will be padded to 12.

```
if_else(nchar(x) >= 12, 
  true = stringr::str_pad(x, 13, side = "left", pad = 0),
  false =  stringr::str_pad(x, 10, side = "left", pad = 0)
)
# [1] "0102030301"    "0223456783"    "5234567123"    "0916784443214"
```

Using `str_pad` in both cases feels safer, since you say you want the resulting number of digits to be 13 if it starts at 12 or more (though this will not reduce inputs with 14 or more digits).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution using Gregor's approach but limited to your exact examples:

```
x <- c(102030301,223456783,5234567123,916784443214)
x2 <- as.character(x)
k <- sapply(x2, function(z) if (nchar(z) == 12 | nchar(z) == 9) { z = paste0("0", z) } else {z})
k
      102030301       223456783      5234567123    916784443214 
   "0102030301"    "0223456783"    "5234567123" "0916784443214" 

# if you want to get rid of the names
names(k) <- NULL
k
[1] "0102030301"    "0223456783"    "5234567123"    "0916784443214"
```